# deleting a mark tag within contentEditable div creates a font tag after retyping

Tags: javascript, html

When I use within a `<div contentEditable>` a `<mark>` tag the text is marked as expected.

When I now remove the marked tag with `Backspace` and start retyping some new characters after deleted the last one inside the content editable there is a `<font style="..."><span style="...">new text` created.

```html
<div id="editable" contentEditable>
  Here is some <mark>text</mark> for testing!
</div>
```

This DOM is created after deleting the word text and replaced it with new text.

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="">
  Here is some <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">new text</span>&nbsp;for testing!
</div>
```

How can I make the contentEditable to

1. create the same tag as deleted **or**
2. create no tag at all

when retyping?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling the below function in the delete event by passing the HTML element to the function.

the calling:

```
placeCaretAtEnd(HTML_ELEMENT_OF_THE_CONTENT_EDITABLE);
```

the function:

```
placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
      && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      range.collapse(false);
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
```